# Flex AIR with Jar file on Android

Tags: java, android, air, jar, air-android

Can you include a jar file with a Flex Air App? (the case of using Merapi - allows you to connect Flex to Java classes directly). Can you export the Flex project as a apk file and then pacakge up the java app as Android compatible then upload both?

Comment: i like to know on this as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/

Also, the soon-to-be-released AIR 3 SDK lets you create a Java native extension that lets you include Java code in an AIR for ANdroid app.